# How to disable automatic scrolling to top

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

How can I disable auto scroll to the top of table view when I append new data to data source of it.

The problem is visible in the following gif.

[image]

Edit: Added ViewController, ViewModel and MessageEntity.

Used frameworks are: RxSwift, RxDataSources for reactive datasource of table view.

ViewController:

```
class RabbitMqVC: BaseViewController {

    struct Cells {
        static let message = ReusableCell<MessageCell>(nibName: "MessageCell")
        static let messageTheir = ReusableCell<MessageCellTheir>(nibName: "MessageCellTheir")
    }

    @IBOutlet
    weak var tableView: UITableView!{
        didSet{
            rabbitMqViewModel.sections
                    .drive(tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
                    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
        }
    }

    private let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<RabbitMqViewModel.MessageSections>()
    private let rabbitMqViewModel : rabbitMqViewModel


    init(rabbitMqViewModel: rabbitMqViewModel) {
        self.rabbitMqViewModel = rabbitMqViewModel
        super.init(nibName: "RabbitMqVC", bundle: nil)

        dataSource.configureCell = { _, tableView, indexPath, item in
            let randomNumber = 1.random(to: 2)
            let cell = randomNumber == 1 ? tableView.dequeue(Cells.message, for: indexPath) : tableView.dequeue(Cells.messageTheir, for: indexPath)

            cell.message = item

            return cell
        }

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(Cells.message)
        tableView.register(Cells.messageTheir)
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80

    }

}
```

ViewModel:

```
class RabbitMqViewModel: ViewModel {

    enum MessageSections: AnimatableSectionModelType {

        typealias Item = MessageEntity
        typealias Identity = Int

        case messages(messages: [MessageEntity])

        var items: [Item] {
            switch self {
            case .messages(messages:let messages):
                return messages
            }
        }

        var identity: Int {
            return 1
        }

        init(original: MessageSections, items: [Item]) {

            switch original {
            case .messages:
                self = .messages(messages: items)
            }
        }
    }

    // input
    let didLoad = PublishSubject<Void>()

    //output
    let sections: Driver<[MessageSections]>

    init(service: RabbitMqService,){
        let messages: Observable<[MessageEntity]> = didLoad
                .flatMapLatest { _ -> Observable<[MessageEntity]> in
                    return service.listenMessages()
                }
                .share()

        self.sections = messages
                .map { (messages) -> [RabbitMqViewModel.MessageSections] in
                    var sections: [MessageSections] = []
                    sections.append(.messages(messages: messages))

                    return sections
                }
                .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])


    }


}
```

MessageEntity:

```
struct MessageEntity {

    let id: String
    let conversationId: String
    let messageText: String
    let sent: Date
    let isSentByClient: Bool
    let senderName: String
    let commodityClientId : Int?

}

extension MessageEntity: IdentifiableType, Equatable {

    typealias Identity = Int

    public var identity: Identity {
        return id.hashValue
    }
    public static func ==(lhs: MessageEntity, rhs: MessageEntity) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing after added new row? tableView.reloadData?

Comment: No. I compute changeset

Comment: How? Could you provide code?

Comment: Please add a code snippet related to how you are inserting a new bubble.

Comment: Do not reload all tableview, Just add cell at last index in tableview

Comment: Missing code added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
estimatedRowHeight = 1
```

Fixed it.